# Custom Alignment of RadioButtons in Android

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, alignment

I have 4 RadioButtons (part of same RadioGroup) and I want to align them like this :
[image]

Code I am using is :

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/add_reminder_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/add_reminder_daily"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add_reminder_daily" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/add_reminder_weekly"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add_reminder_weekly" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/add_reminder_monthly"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add_reminder_monthly" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/add_reminder_yearly"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add_reminder_yearly" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
```

But by using this code, **RadioGroup loses its property and all the RadioButtons can be checked at same time**.

**Any idea how RadioGroup can retain its property** using this type of alignment ?

Comment: @Hemant : I want only one radio button to be checked at once (as they are part of 1 RadioGroup)

Comment: @Amardeep : This code is just a part of my XML which is used to make radio group

Comment: check my updated ans... android:checked="true" used in any radio button

Comment: Please give the reason of down voting this question!
Or you always down vote questions which you can't answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try This....

first declare all radio button

```
r1=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.add_reminder_daily);
 r2=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.add_reminder_weekly);
 r3=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.add_reminder_monthly);
 r4=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.add_reminder_yearly);
```

now on - onclick listner do

```
r1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    r2.setChecked(false);
                    r3.setChecked(false);
                    r4.setChecked(false);
            }
        });
 r2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    r1.setChecked(false);
                    r3.setChecked(false);
                    r4.setChecked(false);
            }
        });
 r3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    r2.setChecked(false);
                    r1.setChecked(false);
                    r4.setChecked(false);
            }
        });
 r4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                    r2.setChecked(false);
                    r3.setChecked(false);
                    r1.setChecked(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes it can be done using java code but is there any way to do it from XML only ?

Answer (score -2):

try below code works fine at my end:-

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/add_reminder_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/add_reminder_daily"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Daily" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/add_reminder_weekly"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Monthly" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/add_reminder_monthly"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Weekly" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/add_reminder_yearly"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yearly" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: I asked "Any idea how RadioGroup can retain its property using this type of alignment ?"

I added a comment for this to my question so that everyone can read it there only

Answer (score -2):

use this code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/add_reminder_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/add_reminder_daily"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="daily" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/add_reminder_weekly"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="weekly" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/add_reminder_monthly"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="monthly" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/add_reminder_yearly"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yearly" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Please see the comment I added to my question

Comment: Have you read the question completely ??
--> I want only one radio button to be checked at once (as they are part of 1 RadioGroup)

Comment: 1 RadioGroup having 4 RadioButtons aligned as shown in image
Problem is --> RadioGroup loses its property "only 1 button can be checked", due to the alignment.
Solution looking for --> Have same alignment and still RadioGroup retain its property.
Clear now ??